# Strict comparison in javascript for usage outside equality?

Tags: javascript

Javascript has the [`===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) and [`!==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_inequality) operators for a strict isEquals test. Is there any way to do this on the other comparison operators? If not, what is the idiomatic way to do that check? For example, with the following 6 comparisons (the last four don't exist):

- Equals: `1 === "1"`
- Does not equal: `1 !== "1"`
- Greater than or equal to: `1 >== "1"` (doesn't exist)
- Less than or equal to: `1 <== "1"` (doesn't exist)
- Greater than: `1 > "1"` (but without cast)
- Less than: `1 < "1"` (but without cast)

Comment: What is`1 >== "1"` even supposed to mean?

Comment: I made it up. It's "Greater than or equals to with strict equality".

Comment: Can you describe the check you'd like to do?  How would it work?

Comment: Let me think about that and give a few cases. I suppose this version would error if there are ever mismatched types, but let me think...

Comment: Seems like you're trying to combine a `typeof` check followed by a comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check whether two values have the same type and the one is greater/lesser than the other, test that explicitly:

```
typeof a === typeof b && a < b
typeof a === typeof b && a <= b
typeof a === typeof b && a >= b
typeof a === typeof b && a > b
```

There are no builtin operators for this, and they are rarely necessary anyway. In idiomatic code, it is clear which type of value a variable has, so you won't need to check it.

Comment: I see, this is what I'm looking for. Is this a common pattern in javascript to get around the cast-to-string that it often does on comparisons?

Comment: @David542 No, it is not common to compare values of different types. And no, JS does not cast to strings when it does comparisons, it attempts to coerce an object to any primitive value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a strict version of those operators, but you could improvise with type checks first. ex:

```js
a = 1;
b = "2";
console.log(a < b);
console.log(typeof a == typeof b && a < b);
```